# Python, Deep Link directing User to Bot Private Chat after Button click

Tags: python, bots, telegram, deep-linking

I have a question that I can‘t resolve it. I am using Telebot API to create a Telegram Bot, all I want to do is, when Bot sends a Button in a Group, when User clicks this Button first time, to be redirected in the Bots Private Message "http://telegram.me/<Bot_Username>?start=start", where User can Start the Bot.

My code in Python:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: 'begin_config' in call.data)
def query(call):
    bot.message.reply_to(text="http://telegram.me/<BotName>?start=start")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['bot_config'])
def bot_config(message):
    text_to_post = "Greetings, Bot here, hit the Button to configure"
    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Bot configuration',                callback_data='begin_config'))
    bot.reply_to(message, text_to_reply, reply_markup=markup)
```

I am getting the Error: AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message'

When I use

call.message.reply_markup(text="http://telegram.me/?start=start")

I am getting the Error: AttributeError: TypeError: 'InlineKeyboardMarkup' object is not callable

I just want User, when he clicks the Button [Bot configuration] first time to get the Private Chat of the Bot, where the User can start the Bot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMCGv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for anyone attempting to solve  my Problem, but I solved it by myself. It was unclear for me since Bot can't send Private Messages to Users, as long as they have not Start-ed the Bot. So I wanted to redirect the User to Start my Bot, by clicking the Button posted by the Bot in the Group.

In this case the Callback is not needed at all, just create a Button containing the Bots Address as Url and send it to ChatID, when User clicks the Button, it automatically invites the User to Start the Bot, after that User can Start the Bot and can get Private Messages.

```
markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Bot configuration',
                    url="https://t.me/<Bot_Name>"))
bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, caption=text_to_post, 
              reply_markup=markup, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
```